# Java on Windows - Programs work with either x86 or x64 of Java, but not with both

Tags: windows-8.1, 64-bit, java, 32-bit

I have a problem with `Java` on my `Windows 8.1`. The problem is that programs work with either `32-bit` or `64-bit` version of `Java`, but not with both.

So, when some program work with `32-bit` version, I have to reinstall that. If some other program works with `64-bit`, again I have to reinstall that. But again, if some other program requires 32-bit version, I have to reinstall that version.

In other words, I cannot use two programs which require two different versions of `Java` at the same time.

What is the proper way to overcome this issue?

Comment: Install both and switch as needed. See [so] question [Switch between 32-bit and 64-bit JDK platform on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16949091)

Comment: So, you are suggesting me to set Java path in IDE (if it's an IDE), od change system PATH variable manually each time when I need to start some Java based application. I've already known that. I was hopping there is some more practical solution. But thanks, anyway.

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to change JAVA_HOME as well. You can do this in a batch file ...

Comment: For JAVA_HOME I can do that in batch file, but for PATH I cannot. At least unless I make some utility app for that.

Comment: You can set the path as well in a batch file. See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342)